# Autorun for usb webserver

Tags: php, windows-10, webserver, usb-drive, autorun

Ok I hope this make sense. I remember back in the day were CD/DVD there was a auto run feature to start file automatically.
`[autorun]  open=Filename.exe`
Now I've read since windows 10 this feature isn't really worth using anymore and it wont work well with USB which brings up my issue.
On my usb card I have alot of work files that needs a portable webserver. I think I may have found one but not sure. I plug it in I manually have to start `server.exe` and when it loads it wants you to start the server by pressing "Server Start" now my question is there and auto run that will start both the `server.exe`and "Server Start" this way all I have to is plug in the USB and everything is done so I can do my work. Or do you recommend an easier way in general I'm open to suggestion. I do know some things about scripts but depending what it is I may need some clarification. Thanks

Comment: i think you must at least show us your try with php code.

Comment: '[autorun] 
open=server.exe 
icon=server.ico'  In theory this should auto run the server once plugged in. Well once server is open you manually have to turn the server on itself before any php work can be done. My problem isn't opening the php file its having the server "itself" starts after it loads from the autorun. So i can work on php files Hope that helps

Comment: you have 1 upvote from me, i hope some windows expert come and help you, and i suggest you to add windows tag in your question

Comment: Thank you I will change the tags.

Comment: Another question? Sorry, to be a pest.. I been sitting here wracking my mind into overload trying to figure an easy way to do this. Is there a way that when the usb is plugged in to any device that it will launch everything as a background service? If so how would I do that?